# A button is bottom and a another button is top, why?

Tags: css, button, position

I have a problem with 2 buttons with CSS. I want to align two buttons next to each other. But CSS does not even like I wanted it. Because a button is bottom and a another button is top. See image: http://home.arcor.de/freedownload/buttonwrong.jpg

Maybe you have a solution for me? That would be fully appreciated.

Here is HTML Code:

```
<head>
<link href="formular.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<span id="form1"><input type="text" id="form_username" name="username"></span><span id="form2"><input type="image" src="loginbutton.png"></span>
```

And here is CSS Code:

```
#form_username {
    background: white url(username.png) left no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px;
    color: #adadad;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    outline: 3px solid #efefef;
}
```

Comment: JSFiddle would be nice. Have you tried removing padding: 8px?

Comment: I have already tried it. It did not work. I work with JSFiddle.. but only I can't to find a solution.

Comment: @mangosaft: do you get why he is asking for a jsfiddle? It's so we can SEE the code. We don't really care if YOU use it but it's about US: the community; the people who might be willing to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this style to your `#form_username`

```
float: left;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pyaaJ/)

Comment: float: left will automatically make the element displayed as a block, so only float would be enough :)